# Why is saying Error(37,45): PLS-00302: component 'CVE_BUYER_LIST_ID' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know why it is saying that is not delcare if i just declared it.

I declared this

```
  PROCEDURE CPSP_CUR_BUYER_LIST (
            in_id              IN crt_buyer.cve_buyer_list_id%TYPE,
            out_cur_buyer_data OUT cursor_type,
            out_respuesta      OUT NUMBER,
            out_mensaje_error  OUT VARCHAR2
    );
```

i keep getting this error
Error(37,45): PLS-00302: component 'CVE_BUYER_LIST_ID' must be declared

Comment: What is the schema name (in which you're creating that procedure)? What does `select * From user_objects where object_name = 'CRT_BUYER'` return?

Comment: It appears that your procedure is owned by one oracle user, while the procedure call is made logged  on as a different user than the procedure owner. A grant execute on CPSP_CUR_BUYER_LIST to applicatio_user (whatever that user is, for I know not), run logged on as the procedure owner should solve the problem. To see whether it is a grant problem, logged on as the application user: select * from all_objects where object_name='CPSP_CUR_BUYER_LIST'. OH! You said the message says: "component 'CVE_BUYER_LIST_ID' ", while the procedure is called CPSP_CUR_BUYER_LIST. The code for that procedure?